# Laravel - Add class to any nav-link if its generated url matches the current route

Tags: html, css, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

I'm working with Bootsrtap 4 and I'm trying to add the class `active` to my `nav-item` elements *whenever* their nav-link `href` attribute is the same as the current url.

On the html side, I uesd a basic url generator as shown below:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/brands') }}" role="button">Brands</a>
    </li>

    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

And then I used a jQuery method to compare them with the current url:

```
$('.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link').each( () => {
    // If the current path and the link url are the same...
    if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf(location.pathname) !== 1) {
        // ...then add the class 'active' to 'nav-item', its parent
        $(this).parent().addClass('active')
    }
})
```

**However**, I noticed that `$(this).attr('href')` was `undefined`, probably because it's a generated url, and therefore `nav-item` doesn't get the `active` class.

**EDIT:** as an example, for now it's a very basic url, without parameter, which looks like this:
*http://domain.example/brands*

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give an example for one of these generated urls? Maybe it's worth to go for regular expressions.

Comment: To match my answer correctly to your question, you should adapt it. You are asking for help with a jQuery specific issue. At least this was not your problem, if I got it right. You wanted to style links inside your navigation to be toggled as soon the current route match. Others could complain, that my answer does not fit to your question. If you need help, just ask for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you to go another way. Instead of "activating" the link with jQuery, you could easily do it server-side with Laravel:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="{{ Request::is('brands*') ? 'nav-link active' : 'nav-link' }}"
           href="{{ url('/brands') }}" 
           role="button">Brands</a>
    </li>

    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

**Explanation**:

*Laravel uses the template-engine twig for rendering the HTML server-side. Instead of manipulation the DOM client-side, you can easily add an conditional to check for the current request parameters. Laravel gives you nativeliy the possibility to check the request path even with a wildcard.*

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is what i do generally do in all my laravel projects when it comes to make sidebar or any link "active" on click :-

```
<li class="nav-item {{ in_array(Route::currentRouteName(),[
            'admin.dashboard',
            'admin.updates',
        ])? 'active show' : ''}}">
          <a href="" class="nav-link with-sub"><i class="typcn typcn-clipboard"></i>Dashboard</a>
          <nav class="nav-sub">
            <a href="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}" class="nav-sub-link {{  BladeHelper::sideBar_link_isActive('admin.dashboard') }}">Home</a>
          </nav>
</li>
```

Now notice this `{{  BladeHelper::sideBar_link_isActive('admin.dashboard') }}`

I created dynamic helper function to get the current url and return "active" class

Path : app\Helpers\BladePageHelper

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Route;
class BladePageHelper
{
    public static function sideBar_link_isActive($selectedLink){
        $currentRouteName = Route::currentRouteName();
        if($selectedLink === $currentRouteName){
            return 'active';
        }else{
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using route name here like

`Route::("/","MyController@mymethod")->name("myname")`

You can do this with url too.

I hope this helps.

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely caused by the difference between using `() => {}` or `function () {}`
When you use the arrow syntax the prop `this` is unbound. Meaning that also `$(this)` will return an empty jQuery object instead of returning the anchor. Any follow up jQuery chaining will return something empty/undefined.

So, changing `.each( () => {` to `.each(function() {` will at least  fix your undefined problem.

Information about the arrow syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions